# Generate list from user input

Tags: python, regex, list, python-3.x, python-3.4

How could I have a user input something like `Blah Blah [1-30] Blah` and then parse it to get a list like so:

```
[
    'Blah Blah 1 Blah',
    'Blah Blah 2 Blah',
    etc...
    'Blah Blah 30 Blah',
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex. First find the start and end points ,specified by `[a-b]`. Then loop them, and replace these brackets by the increasing number:

```
import re
expr = input('Enter expression: ') # Blah Blah [1-30] Blah
start, end = map(int, re.findall('(\d+)-(\d+)', expr)[0])
my_list = [re.sub('\[.*\]', str(i), expr) for i in range(start, end + 1)]

>>> pprint(my_list)
['Blah Blah 1 Blah',
 'Blah Blah 2 Blah',
 ...
 'Blah Blah 29 Blah',
 'Blah Blah 30 Blah']
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited to your needs:

```
import re
seqre = re.compile("\[(\d+)-(\d+)\]")
s = "Blah Blah [1-30] blah"

seq = re.findall(seqre, s)[0]
start, end = int(seq[0]), int(seq[1])

l = []
for i in range(start, end+1):
    l.append(re.sub(seqre, str(i), s))
```

Comment: This is in python 3 :P but I wanted the user to input one line and then the program to generate the list.

Comment: Would the line have certain delimiters? For example a comma?

Comment: I could do input().split(', ') but the problem with that it that the user would have to type out j1, j2, j3, etc... instead of j[1-10]

Comment: The new answer doesn't work. Something with how you are getting the start -- [135,136] returns [5,6,7,8,...,136]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use regex you could try something like this using [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
user_input = input('Please enter your input e.g. blah blah [1-30] blah:')

list_definiton = (user_input[user_input.find('[')+len(']'):user_input.rfind(']')])

minimum = int(list_definiton.split('-')[0])
maximum = int(list_definiton.split('-')[1])

core_string = user_input.split('[' + list_definiton + ']')

string_list = []
for number in range(minimum, maximum + 1):
  string_list.append("%s%d%s" % (core_string[0], number, core_string[1]))

print(string_list)
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/EsyE/1)

Comment: It works just fine, but the regex is shorter and clearer. Thanks for your answer though.