# Tryin to create a list from user input

Tags: python

this is my first posting here as I am a newbie with python and I would appreciate your help.
I am trying to create a list with user input using the code below, but when running it only prints out the first line without prompting for the input and nothing else happens !
Can you please show me where the error is ?
(edit) The issue I am facing is with SublimeText but when I tried it with an online compiler it worked just fine ! Any idea on where the problem is ? 
'

```
ln = int(raw_input("Enter the lenght of your list :"))
 l = []
 i = 0
 print ("Enter the elements of you list : ") 
 while i < ln :
     list_element = int (raw_input ())
     l.append(list_element)
     i += 1
 print (l)
```

`
I am using python 2.7

Comment: it works for me on my cli. do you get an error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate list from user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212721/generate-list-from-user-input)

Comment: @Asthmatic no it doesn't get any error message, it just print the "Enter the lenght of your list :" message and then nothing else happen !

Comment: @JacobB I know there is other methods but I just want to find where the error is in my code so I can avoid this error in the future. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python will give u error if the indentation is not proper it works same as braces'{}' in 
 other languages which shows inside coding

```
elements = raw_input('Enter elements, separated by commas ') #i used input() in 
l = []    # problem is here 
temp = elements.split(',')
for item in temp:
    try:
        l.append(int(item))
    except ValueError:
        print(item,'is not an integer - was not added to list')
print(l)
```

There are many alternatives to this solution like input

```
# Reads two numbers from input and typecasts them to int using  
# list comprehension 
x, y = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
```

or

```
# Reads two numbers from input and typecasts them to int using  
# map function 
x, y = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

Answer (score 1):

looking at your example I would say it's because everything after your `ln` variable is indented. Python is a very strict when it comes to indentation. 
This should fix your problem. :)

```
ln = int(raw_input("Enter the lenght of your list :"))
l = []
i = 0
print ("Enter the elements of you list : ") 
while i < ln :
    list_element = int (raw_input ())
    l.append(list_element)
    i += 1
print (l)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it did work, but maybe the indentation show in the question could be the problem? However, there are other alternatives to let the user add elements to a list. e.g. you could just ask them for the elements:

```
elements = raw_input('Enter elements, separated by commas ') #i used input() in python3
l = []
temp = elements.split(',')
for item in temp:
    try:
        l.append(int(item))
    except ValueError:
        print(item,'is not an integer - was not added to list')
print(l)
```

As a side note, if you were to assume that all elements to be input are always going to be integers, you could just do:

`l = [int(x) for x in elements.split(',')]`

Comment: thank you for your answer, as I mentioned in the edit above, I am facing this issue when running the code on Sublimetext but when I tried it on an online compiler it worked fine ! Any idea what the problem is ?